# How to distribute iPad app by ad hoc methods

Tags: ipad

I have been working on a productivity app for 5 members of a company. I installed the app onto the iPads myself before sending them out. Now how do I send updated versions of the app to them?

The Apple site says ad hoc distribution can be done by email or from a web server but so far I can't find anything that explains HOW the app gets installed onto the iPad. Has anyone done this or knows how it is done? I figure some action on the part of the end user is needed which maybe a sticking point...

I'm correct in thinking that the app will run until the provisioning profile on the device expires and then be useless right?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distribute the ad hoc build along with the provisioning profile that contains the users UDID via email, website, however you want. **The tester simply drops the certificate and app onto iTunes and syncs.**

If the provisioning profile expires for the user, simply generate a new one and distribute it along with the new build of the app.

Comment: Alright, that sounds like what I need. Pity the lifetime of the app is limited but its better than nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you distribute applications via the ad hoc method, no application artwork is displayed when the user looks at your application inside the iTunes interface. However, if you place a copy of the 512×512-pixel PNG of your icon in your application bundle and name it iTunesArtwork without any file extension, this will be used by iTunes.

To deploy your application to your users via the ad hoc method, you need to create a distribution certificate, register any devices you plan to use, and create an ad hoc provisioning profile in the iPhone Developer Program Portal.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this yet, but bookmarked it because it looks interesting: http://www.readwriteweb.com/mobile/2010/12/apple-best-kept-secret-how-to-do-ad-hoc-installs.php

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a CI server, I have a [quick slide deck and some supporting files for my system](http://jamesjennin.gs/post/2788994074/saving-time-money-through-build-automation-intro-to), which uses Hudson to automate the build process, as well as deploy the app for OTA intallation. End result is when I commit something to SVN, my clients get an email a few minutes later with a link that directly installs the new app on their phone.

If you don't have that infrastructure set up (or aren't looking to take it on as a project), I've been hearing great things about http://testflightapp.com/, although I can't say I've used them myself.